# Debian - How I can delete things related to the GUI?

Tags: debian, command-line, package-management, gui, delete

I installed Debian for CLI purposes.
How I can delete things related to the GUI without the system crashing (Because I do not need GUI packages to free up memory)?

Comment: What did you use to install? Debian netinst comes without any sort of GUI afaik.

Comment: @Panki netinst installs GNOME by default.

Comment: In the "Software selection" screen during installation, you probably had the option of installing any of "Debian desktop environment", "GNOME", "Xfce", "GNOME Flashback", "KDE Plasma", "Cinnamon", "MATE", "LXDE", "LXQt", "web server", "SSH server", and "laptop".  Do you remember what you selected?  If you only selected "Debian desktop environment" or "GNOME", then `sudo apt purge gnome` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Stewart  None, but some packages were GUI specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should delete most GUI applications and libraries:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove libx11-6 libwayland-client0
```

> How I can delete things related to the GUI without the system crashing

Linux (distros) will not crash without the GUI. The only two things required for Linux to run are the kernel and the init process. The init process technically doesn't do anything itself, so to be completely correct, you need three pieces: the kernel, the init process and something else which actually does something, e.g. `busybox`. `busybox` itself may be the init process, so we're back to just two components, the kernel and some process doing something.